# how to merge rows summing over each column without iteration

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization

I have the following `df`:

```
   prevent     _p     _n  _id
0        1      0      0  83135
0        0      1      0  83135
0        0      1      0  82238
```

I would like to merge all rows having the same column `_id`by summing over each column for
the desired output in a dataframe, `final` (please note that if thee sum is greater than 1, the value should just be 1):

```
     prevent     _p     _n  _id
0          1      1      0  83135
0          0      1      0  82238
```

I can easily do this using the following code iterating over the dataframe:

```
final = pd.DataFrame()
for id_ in _ids:
        
        out = df[df._id == id_]
        
        prevent = 0
        _p = 0
        _n = 0

        d = {}

        if len(out) > 0:

            for row in out.itertuples():
                if prevent == 0:
                    prevent += row.prevent
                if _p == 0:
                   _p += row._p
                if _n == 0:
                   _n += row._n
               
            d['_p'] = _p
            d['_n'] = _n
            d['prevent'] = prevent
           
            t=pd.DataFrame([d])
            t['_id'] = id_
            final=pd.concat([final, t])
```

I have several hundred thousand rows, so this will be very inefficient. Is there a way to vectorize this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Treat 0 and 1 as boolean with `any`, then convert them back to integers:

```py
df.groupby("_id").any().astype("int").reset_index()
```

Comment: Simpler than I was expecting.

Answer (score 1):

Check `groupby`

```
out = df.groupby('_id',as_index=False).sum()
```